# Calculate a fraction based on multiple conditions

Tags: stata

I have data in Stata in this format:

| Value | Treatment | Area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2.5 | 1 | 2 |
| 3.4 | 0 | 3 |
| 6.7 | 0 | 1 |
| 3.6 | 0 | 2 |
| 2.9 | 1 | 3 |
| 2.5 | 0 | 1 |
| 7.8 | 1 | 3 |

I want to get a sum of the values in "Value" by area and by treatment status. This part I was able to do using:

```
by Area Treatment, sort: egen desired_variable = total(Value)
```

What I want is for each row of the dataset, a sum of the values in "Value" for all the treated AND untreated observations in the area. The issue with this is that it gives me the total for Treatment = 1 and Treatment = 0 for each Area, depending on its own treatment status.

I also tried:

```
by Area, sort: egen desired_variable = total(Value) if treatment == 1
```

and

```
by Area, sort: egen desired_variable = total(Value) if treatment == 0
```

But this is a different version of the same problem, since in a row where the treatment is = 0, the first line of code will just give an NA, and vice versa with the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of calculation is sometimes needed:

```
clear
input float value byte(treatment area)
1.1 1 1
2.5 1 2
3.4 0 3
6.7 0 1
3.6 0 2
2.9 1 3
2.5 0 1
7.8 1 3
end

bysort area: egen total1 = total(cond(treatment == 1, value, .)) 
by area: egen total0 = total(cond(treatment == 0, value, .))
```

See also Section 9 in https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1101100210

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need to make the last sum conditional on treatment at all. Is there any reason the example below does not work for you?

```
clear
input float value byte(treatment area)
1.1 1 1
2.5 1 2
3.4 0 3
6.7 0 1
3.6 0 2
2.9 1 3
2.5 0 1
7.8 1 3
end

* Sum of value by area and treatment
bysort area treatment : egen var1 = total(value)

* Sum of value by area
bysort area : egen var2 = total(value)
```

If `treatment` has more values than 0 and 1, then change the last line to `bys area : egen var2 = total(value) if inlist(treatment, 0, 1)`